# Why is StreamWriter adding in an extra blank line while File.WriteAllLine does not?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, streaming, streamwriter

I was originally using File.WriteAllLines to write out a large list of records to a local text file. This list is set to expand, so to avoid any memory issues I decided to follow the advice given in  [SqlClient Streaming Support MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . The altered code that I am currently using is included below.

```
  using (FileStream destFile = new FileStream(
                       destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destFile))
                    {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
                        int charsRead = 0;
                        using (TextReader data = reader.GetTextReader(0))
                        {
                                do
                                {
                                    charsRead = await data.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(buffer, 0, charsRead);
                                }
                                while (charsRead > 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The file that is created as a result of running this code (using writer.WriteLineAsync) **includes an unwanted blank line between each record**, though the outputted data is correct. Originally I used the  [SqlQuery method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)  together with  a foreach loop and added each record into a generic collection. I then used File.WriteAllLines to output the records to the specified file and the records were **formatted without blank lines** between them (**the desired result**).

To try to resolve this issue (instead of using writer.WriteLineAsync), I then tried to use

```
writer.WriteAsync
```

but all of the text was outputted to one row.

I researched stackoverflow for some advice and came across posts suggesting the use of

```
writer.NewLine ="\n\r" or writer.NewLine ="\r"
```

This unfortunately did not fix the problem. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of this:

```
charsRead = await data.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
await writer.WriteLineAsync(buffer, 0, charsRead);
```

Whenever `charsRead` is `0`, you still write a line. Change it to

```
charsRead = await data.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
if (charsRead > 0)
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(buffer, 0, charsRead);
```

Or, if you want to write a single line for each record, change it to:

```
do
{
    charsRead = await data.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (charsRead > 0)
        await writer.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, charsRead);
}
while (charsRead > 0);
await writer.WriteLineAsync(buffer, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @JohnMack I am glad that worked for you. You may want to accept it as the answer by checking the checkmark next to this answer, to allow your question to be removed from the "unanswered questions" list.  Refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)